# Remote triggering by using optoisolators

Tags: signal-integrity, trigger

I need to hardware-trigger three modules from a pulse signal source.
According to their data-sheet each module requires between 5 to 15V for trigger high and 0 to 5V for low. Each module draw around 6mA so the input impedance is around 2.3k.

The triggering source on the other hand is a pulse train at a fixed frequency 32Hz will come from [this](https://www.mccdaq.com/pdfs/manuals/USB-1616FS.pdf) DAQ hardware sync output. The sync output is only 5V. Here is sync output specs(At 32Hz short duty cycle worries me):

[image]

Anyway, the distance from the control source and a module can vary between 10 meters up to 50 meters.

I have two main challenges here:

-The first one is to send trigger from a single source to three modules.

-The second one is the length which can be max 50 meters.

Some suggested to use differential line transmitters with multiple outputs. But the data-sheet of the module says it needs to be 5V and 15V to be triggered.
So that means the transmitted differential signal must be converted back to single ended signal right before the module.

Another user suggested to isolate the outputs at the module end.

A while ago I had asked [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/373123/hardware-triggering-multiple-devices-from-a-single-source-for-long-distances) related question.

One of the answer was simpler to implement. Since it requires less electronics, I decided to try optoisolator way at module ends.

Below is the diagram showing that scheme:

[image]
[left-click to zoom in]

As you see a DAQ's 5V 32Hz sync output is triggering all three modules at once. Vp1, Vp1, Vp3 separate power supplies for each module. Optoisolator is right before the module. Rg1, Rg2 and Rg3 are just to indicate and simulate that the grounds of opto input and output are isolated. A STP cable can be be used.

It is okay to have some noise or glitch sometimes at the trigger input.

I just need most of the pulses arrive to the module as clean and accurate as possible I can to. Do you think at 32 Hz for around 50 meters length I can trigger those three modules as in the scheme and proper way? What can be modified if necessary?

**edit:**

[Photo-darlingtons](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81865/4n324n33.pdf)(4N32) used, a buffer for sync added, STP used:

[image]

Comment: The opto If current looks a low (what is worst case CTR and allowance for temperature/aging effects?), also I don't see any spec on the drive capability of the source.

Comment: I found more detailed module for the module:http://scanivalve.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/MPS4264_V205-1.pdf At page 23 it says: "The external hardware trigger voltage is input through pins 4 & 5 of the power connector. The trigger is 5-15Vdc, 6.5mA." .. But it doesn't say whether the trigger input has hysteresis.

Comment: The source may not drive but I can make a buffer after the sync; that is not a problem, assume it can drive. Im more curious about whether this opto way and wiring correct.

Comment: Can you get the 12V or whatever at the far end rather than sending it?

Comment: If you mean placing the power supplies right next to the modules, yes it is possible but then I have to extend  the AC mains cables upto there which is okay.

Comment: It will probably work reliably as drawn if you drive the optos a bit harder, maybe 10mA or add emitter followers at the far end. It would be better if just the wires went to the optos and if the wires were shielded twisted pair. The optos are slow enough  (some kHz) to filter out reflections and such. Photodarlingtons could be used rather than emitter followers but they will be slower again.

Comment: I tried to modify following your comments please see my edit or check out here https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsNor.png Photo-darlingtons(4N32) used, a buffer for sync added, STP used. Do you think more reliable?

Comment: Consider reducing R12 etc. to 1K and reducing R8 to 3K and R13 to 3K or 4.7K.

Comment: Thanks one more but very important thing Im really worried and not sure. As you see this scheme requires four 12V power supplies Vp1 Vp2 Vp3 and Vp4 in the schematics. If I use just one 12V supply for all(means all supplies will share common ground), would this scheme be useless?

Comment: Might be worth trying it with one 12V supply at the signal source. It will work but may be more susceptible to noise.

Comment: The IR diodes can be put in series on 5V with a small R for rated current. Shielded pairs are needed but how far apart are the sensors?